# Doctrine @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE") and empty DiscriminatorMap value

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

i try setup reference with discriminator but have error when i try get subdomain for miejsce - mysql update work fine

error is : 
    An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.name AS name2, t0.rid AS rid3, t0.rid AS rid4, t0.ridType FROM mSubdomains t0 WHERE t0.rid = ? AND t0.ridType IN ()' with params ["5922"]:

is normal to params is only miejsce.id ? ridType should by 1

when i push this query to phpmyadmin i get :

```
SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.name AS name2, t0.rid AS rid3, t0.rid AS rid4, t0.ridType
FROM mSubdomains t0
WHERE t0.rid =5922
AND t0.ridType
IN ( 1 )
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

and result :

```
id1     name2   rid3    rid4    ridType     
1695    test    5922    5922    1
```

strange is rid3 , rid4  ?

```
class Miejsce
{
...
   /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Miejsce\DomainBundle\Entity\MiejsceSubdomain", mappedBy="miejsce", cascade={"all"})
     * @var Subdomain
     */
    protected $subdomain;
```

if MiejsceSubdomain is not abstract i get error  :

MappingException: Entity 'Miejsce\DomainBundle\Entity\MiejsceSubdomain' has to be part of the discriminator map of 'Miejsce\DomainBundle\Entity\Subdomain' to be properly mapped in the inheritance hierachy. Alternatively you can make 'Miejsce\DomainBundle\Entity\Miej`sceSubdomain' an abstract class to avoid this exception from occuring.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
abstract class MiejsceSubdomain extends Subdomain
{

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Miejsce\ObiektyBundle\Entity\Miejsce")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="rid", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $miejsce;

}



/**
 * Subdomain
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="ridType", type="integer")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"1" = "Miejsce\ObiektyBundle\Entity\Miejsce"})
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="mSubdomains", indexes={
    @ORM\Index(name="name", columns={"name"})
    ,@ORM\Index(name="ridridType", columns={"rid","ridType"})
}))
 */
class Subdomain
{


    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @var string
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @var integer
     */
    private $rid;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DiscriminatorMap should point to children of Subdomain entity.
change:

- @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"1" = "Miejsce\ObiektyBundle\Entity\Miejsce"})

to:

- @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"1" = "Miejsce\ObiektyBundle\Entity\MiejsceSubdomain"})

And remove `abstract` from `MiejsceSubdomain` class.
Also rename `MiejsceSubdomain` to `SubdomainMiejsce`.